# creating thumbnail from a video using ffmpeg in php exec() returns 1 but returns 0 if command is 'ffmpeg -h'

Tags: php, video, ffmpeg

creating thumbnail from a video using ffmpeg in php exec() returns 1 but returns 0 if command is 'ffmpeg -h'. i am using ubuntu. A portion of my code is as shown bellow. When i tried $cmd it returned 1 and when i tried $cmd1 it worked.

```
$ffmpeg = 'ffmpeg';
$getFromSecond = 5;
$videoFile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
$size = '105x73';
$imageFile = 'Newimage.jpg';

$cmd = "$ffmpeg -an -ss $getFromSecond -i $videoFile -vframes 1 -s $size $imageFile";
$cmd1 = "$ffmpeg -h";
```

works for $cmd1 but not for $cmd, i am thinking it is permission issues

Comment: Then if you think it's permissions issue, run the command from SSH and check what happens. All that you can get from here is "it's probably permissions issue".

Comment: got it working by adding  ' 2>&1 &', the command then looks like this exec($cmd . ' 2>&1 &', $output, $retrival); but i am now having the error [image2 @ 0xf25f20] Could not open file : home/perfection/Pictures/Newimage.jpg" [34]=> string(48) "av_interleaved_write_frame(): Input/output error